# Fetch values between two [] from a string using Regular expressions

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string like as folows :

```
"channel_changes":[[1313571300,26.879846,true],[1313571360,26.901025,true]]
```

I want to extract each string in angular brace like `1313571300`, `26.879846`, `true`

through regular expression.

I have tried using

```
string regexPattern = @"\[(.*?)\]";
```

but that gives the first string as `[[1313571420,26.901025,true]`
i.e with one extra angular brace.

Please help me how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work in Expresso for me:

```
\[([\w,\.]*?)\]
```

> Literal [
>   [1]: A numbered capture group. [[\w,.]*?]
>   - Any character in this class: [\w,.], any number of repetitions, as few as possible
>   Literal ]

The problem seemed to be the "." in your regex - since it was picking up the first literal "[" and considering the following "[" in your input to be valid as the next character.

I constrained it to just alphanumeric characters, commas and literal full-stops (period mark), since that's all that was present in your example. You could go further and really specify the format of the data inside those inner square brackets assuming it's consistent, and end up with something more like this:

```
\[[0-9.]+,[0-9.]+,(true|false)\]
```

**Example C# code:**

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("\"channel_changes\":[[1313571300,26.879846,true],[1313571360,26.901025,true]]", @"\[([\w,\.]*?)\]");

foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Comment: In .NET it returns 5 matches, where third is comma symbol ',' and fifth is  ']'

Comment: Works in PowerShell, wonder why not in .NET? `[regex]::matches('"channel_changes":[[1313571300,26.879846,true],[1313571360,26.901025,true]]', '\[([\w,\.]*?)\]')`

Comment: I've just tested this in a C# console app and it *appears* to be working. What am I missing? (Answer updated with example code).

Comment: To sllev and user739990: Exactly **how** are you doing this in .NET? I'm interested because I've tested it and it does seem to work for me in Expresso, PowerShell and a .NET C# console application. Care to share, in case the problem isn't in the regex pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@"\[+([^\]]+)\]+"
```

"[^]]+" - it means any character except right square bracket

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\[([^\[\]]*)\]
```

See it here [online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ufnu)

`[^\[\]]*` is a negated character class, means match any character but `[` and `]`. With this construct you don't need the `?` to make your `*` ungreedy.